# $X_n \ \xrightarrow{p}\ 0$. However, the expected value of $X_n$ does not converge to $0$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

While reading *"Introduction to probability, statistics, and random processes" by H. Pishro-Nik*, I encountered example 7.11 in the [7.2.6 chapter](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter7/7_2_6_convergence_in_mean.php),

The example defines a sequence of random variabls  $X_1, X_2, X_3, ...$ such that:

$\begin{equation}
\nonumber X_n = \left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
n^2 & \qquad \textrm{with probability } \frac{1}{n} \\
& \qquad \\
0 & \qquad \textrm{with probability } 1-\frac{1}{n}
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation}$

then it shows that:

1. $X_n \ \xrightarrow{p}\ 0$
2. $X_n$ does not converge in the $r$th mean for any $r≥1$

Then, the example concludes with an interesting fact, which is:

although $X_n \ \xrightarrow{p}\ 0$, the expected value of $X_n$ does not converge to $0$

---

The last fact stated by the example is confusing me a little bit.

If $X_n \ \xrightarrow{p}\ Y$, and $Y$ is r.v. that has a divergent expected value, then the last statment whould make since. However, if $Y$ does have a convergent expected value (in our case it is the degenerate case of the zero<sup>th</sup> r.v.), I do not see why the expected value of $X_n$ does not converge. Why does the definition of convergence in probability fail to guarantee the convergence of the expected value of $X_n$ to $E[Y]$. At the end, the probability of $X_n$ being further from $Y$ by $\epsilon$ do reach $0$ as n grows by definition of convergnece in probability.

Can anyone explain what am I missing?
Thanks,,

Comment: Have you studied some basic Measure Theory? You cannot write $\lim EX_n=E\lim X_n$ in general.

Comment: In the link you cite, they clearly discuss how convergence in the $r$th mean implies convergence in probability, and prove this using Markov's inequality and give a counterexample of the converse. Where is the confusion?

Comment: Thanks @Golden_Ratio . My problem is that I don't understand the counterexample. What confused me is: from the def of convergence in probability, the expected value of $X_n$ would converge to $0$. I stated why I think this is case. I know that is wrong since convergence of probability is weaker that convergence in mean. However, I do not know how this is wrong.

Comment: In the counterexample, the probability of being $0$ increases towards $1$ and of not being $0$ decreases towards $0$.  So you have convergence towards $0$ in probability.  But the mean takes account of the whole distribution and does not ignore the small probability of being non-$0$, and in this case the expected value has been constructed to be $E[X_n]=n$, which increases without limit with $n$. A similar example could target any  desired function of $n$ as the expectation: $P(\,X=n\,f(n)\,)=\frac1n$ and $P(X=0)=1-\frac1n$ while still having convergence towards $0$ in probability.

Comment: Thanks @Henry. That explains it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Copied from comment:*

In the counterexample, the probability of being $0$ increases towards $1$ and of not being $0$ decreases towards $0$. So you have convergence towards $0$ in probability.

But the mean takes account of the whole distribution and does not ignore the small probability of being non-$0$, and in this case the expected value has been constructed to be $E[X_n]=n$, which increases without limit with $n$.

A similar example could target any desired function of $n$ as the expectation: $P(\, X_n=n\,f(n)\,)=\frac1n$ and $P(X_n=0)=1−\frac1n$ while still having convergence towards $0$ in probability.